# Error al intentar ver imagenes con docker

Tags: docker

Hola y me disculpo si por la pregunta un poco básica, simplemente no he podido encontrar a la solución en google.

incerté el comando: `docker images` para poder ver las imagenes instaladas y me salta este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Are you using boot2docker ???

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando boot2docker, quizas esto te sea de ayuda.

```
boot2docker ssh
sudo ntpclient -s -h pool.ntp.org
```

Comment: el idioma oficial para responder en este sitio es el español, así que por favor traduce tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Docker cuenta con una API para la consulta de las imágenes, contenedores, consumo de CPU, etc. El puerto 2376 es el que por defecto usa docker para su consumo. De acuerdo al error me percato que la conexión al servidor para la consulta de la API se está realizando por https y el problema está en que los certificados ya expiraron. Verifique la variable `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` o los certificados que está implementando para la conexión con el Docker Machine